# End bar in musixtex

Tags: musixtex

I know how to type the end bar at the end of a piece in Musixtex using `\startpiece`:

```
\begin{music}
\startpiece
[music code]
\Endpiece
\end{music}
```

I want to type this end bar with `\startextract` instead of `\startpiece`. `\Endextract` doesn't exist and I think I looked for the answer of this very simple question everywhere, and that this very simple question MUST have an answer... Does anyone know?

Comment: I dnot understand your problem. \endstract exists.

Comment: \endextract makes this :
![endextract](https://www.zupimages.net/up/19/33/gcd2.png)
as \endpiece. But if you write \Endpiece instead of \endpiece, you obtain this :
![Endpiece](https://zupimages.net/up/19/33/4k4e.png)
which is what I want : something like \Endextract (and not \endextract !)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quiet sure of your question, however I only give some extra information, hope helps a little bit.

1) The difference of `\endextract` and `\endpiece`is that the former can be used in a `LaTeX` document directly.

2) `\Endpiece` end up with a double bar. Since there's no `\Endextract`, you can use `\setdoublebar` to make the end in double bar. `\setdoubleBAR` can make the double bar thick, as showed in the following example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\input musixlyr
\large\setlyrstrut
 \resetlyrics
 \setlyrics{Winter1}{Win-ter a-de\rlap{,} a-ber dein Schei-den macht\rlap{,}}
 \setlyrics{Winter2}{schei-den tut weh\rlap,}
 \assignlyrics1{Winter1,Winter2}
 \generalmeter{\meterfrac34}
 \generalsignature2
 \setsongraise1{-2mm}
 \startextract
  \NOtes\qa{ffe}\en\bar
  \NOTesp\hup d\en
  \setdoubleBAR
\endextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm quite sure I tried it days ago and that it didn't work, but, in fact... it works. Thank you!